# how to resolve unloaded behaviour in power query add-in in excel 2010?

Tags: excel

I got two different version excel 2007 and 2010 installed in Windows 8.1 2013. All has been well for two weeks, until today I had an infinite loop bug in my Excel(2010) Add-In, so I had to End-task. Ever since then, Excel refuses to show my Power Query Add-In ribbon. I go to Excel Options, Add-Ins, Com Add-Ins, and my add-in shows, but is un-checked and shows as "Unloaded". It refuses to hold the check box.

I also removed and re-installed Power query. Still it is not solved.

I've checked the Disabled Items list many times. It shows as un-checked. I check it, click save. Exit and go back in. Its un-checked. The re-enabling does not stick.

How to solve unloaded behaviour in COM ADD-INS. How to change the Load behaviour : Unloaded to
Load behaviour : Load at Startup? How to get power query ribbon back?